# SSRS reading date type as nvarchar

Tags: reporting-services

I have created a query that uses a decimal as a paramater in SSRS. Code below (`@TrueDemand`) when running this on my local PC, via the Data page the query throws an error of `trying to convert nvarchar to int`.
   However when running it in Preview or even publishing the report to the web it runs fine :(

[image: Error]

Its very frustrating. Any ideas?

```
SELECT  AD.LogDate,
    AD.Location,
    AD.FunctionDescription as Func,
    AD.Offered,
    AD.Handled,
              AD.Handled +  ((AD.Offered - AD.Handled) * @TrueDemand) as TrueDemand,
    AD.Handled30,
    AG.SignedIn,
    AG.Available,
    AG.WorkloadSecs,
    AG.FullAHTSecs

FROM        dbo.vw_ApplicationDetail_Minus15mins AD
INNER JOIN  dbo.vw_AgentGroupDetail AG ON
    AD.Logdate = AG.Logdate AND
    AD.Location = AG.Location AND
    AD.FunctionDescription = AG.FunctionDescription

WHERE AD.Logdate between @Logdate  AND dateadd(d,1,@Logdate) AND
         AD.Location = @Location AND
         AD.FunctionDescription = @Function

ORDER BY AD.Logdate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried explicitly casting to decimal all the variables on that line.

```
cast(AD.Handled as Decimal) + ((Cast(AD.Offered as Decimal) - Cast(AD.Handled as Decimal)) * Cast(@TrueDemand as Decimal)) as TrueDemand
```

Comment: Yes, this works in fact its just the Paramater I needed to cast. Does anyone have any idea why SSRS would read a value of 0.50 as a nvarchar? On further investigation it reads intergers fine.. Feels like a bug?

Comment: Nope! It did not work, casting it to Decimal would only return an Intger. I.E 0.50 = 1. Casting it to float works. Confused :(